# Strange issue with new/old post link in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a issue with wordpress older post link in posts listing page.The wordpress version is 3.8.3.

When I am changing the permalink to default one then it works.But when I change it to custom structure ie /%category%/%postname%/ then onclicking the older post link it takes me to 'page not found'

I have absolutely no clue where the problem is happening.

For eg if the url is

```
http://localhost/folder/?cat=6&paged=2
```

The above url works.

But  `http://localhost/folder/catname/page/2/` //it doesn't work

**Solved**

Comment: It's fixed now. The reference url is http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-34-and-pagination-custom-post-type-error. Please refer to s_zawil reply if anyone has got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your .htaccess file to make that permalinks work.

Check out this detailed article - http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: Ronak I tried with that but not working.I think the wp htaccess is pretty much same for all permalink cases.